# AWS SAM: Build Failed Error: Docker is unreachable. Docker needs to be running to build inside a container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

Im running AWS SAM and using `sam build --use-container` then get the following error.

`Starting Build inside a container Building function 'SamTutorialFunction Build Failed Error: Docker is unreachable. Docker needs to be running to build inside a container`

I run `sudo service docker start` before and still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe the docker service failed. Can you check `systemctl status docker`?

Comment: shows active and running

Answer (score 7):

sudo ln -s "$HOME/.docker/run/docker.sock" /var/run/docker.sock

work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: See also https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/5646#issuecomment-1658320645

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  The problem was that docker was installed to run as the root user.  AWS SAM is trying to access as your logged in user.  You can set docker to run as non-root user (without sudo) by adding your user to the docker group.  See https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: Specifically, on Ubuntu the following commands did the trick for me:
`$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
`$  newgrp docker`

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, and solve it.
On Ubuntu, Docker Desktop runs the docker engine into a Virtual Machine. Sometimes this gives problem for other software to connect with it. The solution I found, was to install docker-engine next to Docker Desktop... yes they can coexist see [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#what-is-the-difference-between-docker-desktop-for-linux-and-docker-engine).

After you installed docker-engine, close Docker Desktop, and try the hello word package to see if the docker-engine you installed is running.

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

Try to run it with and without "sudo". If you have problem without "sudo" check the user permission as suggested [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was that I did not have the `DOCKER_HOST` env variable set, I am using Docker Desktop for Linux so first i ran

```bash
docker context ls
```

to get the `DOCKER ENDPOINT` and set the `DOCKER_HOST` env variable to the endpoint value

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Ubuntu on WSL2, You need to enable integration between Docker and WSL2 in order to run

```
sam build --use-container
```

**Steps:**

1. Download Docker Desktop https://desktop.docker.com/win/main/amd64/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe
2. Go to settings => resources => WSL integration.
3. Check the enable integration with additional distros.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using another tool like [Rancher Desktop](https://rancherdesktop.io), you must start it with `root` access in order to be able to work with `/var/run/docker.sock`.

Search in settings how to enable it in your tool, for **Rancher Desktop** you can go to *Main APP icon > Open preferences dialog* and enable **Administrative Access** option.